# C#, WPF - OpenFileDialog in project path

Tags: c#, wpf, file

Im making a WPF App. What i want to do is open `OpenFileDialog` property in path in project.

**My code:**

```
OpenFileDialog openPicture = new OpenFileDialog();
openPicture.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.tif";
openPicture.FilterIndex = 1;

if (openPicture.ShowDialog() == true) 
{
    string filepath = openPicture.FileName;
}
```

I want to acces `ExampleImages` folder in my project:

[image]

The only solution that i found is using this ([Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568191/how-to-open-specific-path-or-directory-by-default-via-openfiledialog)):

```
openPicture.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath), "FolderName");
```

But it seems like `Application.StartupPath` is hide in `using System.Windows.Forms` and i cant acces it in my WPF app. Can you explain me, how to force `OpenFileDialog` to open into my project folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get current application path in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926506/how-to-get-current-application-path-in-wpf) (`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"..\\..\\ExampleImages"))
```

Note, that you should use this only during development.